# Recommend fast C++ UI library with small memory footprint

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

I want to write an app that reacts for global shortcuts and accepts commands (the way [launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) does).

I'm trying to minimize the time between pressing the shortcut and the moment the window appears on the screen and is fully operational.

Can you suggest a good UI library (with some argumentation) that could be helpful?
I looked into QT and wxWidget but I'm afraid the app will get heavy (in memory / processing speed way) - and all I need is a small window that doesn't even need to be pretty.

.. or should I just go with native Windows libraries? (the main target is my Windows 7 machine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fast? Small? Windows-only? Sounds like you want [WTL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/).

Caveat: You'll need to use VC++.

Also, I recommend grabbing the source straight out of [SVN](http://wtl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/wtl/trunk/), as a new release hasn't been packaged in quite some time despite the fact that the project gets updated with some regularity.

Comment: +1 for WTL. Just a small correction - it can be used with VC++ Express with some tweaking. ATL is now a part of the SDK.

Comment: @Nemanja Trifunovic : Oh, wow, didn't realize ATL was made freely available. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: @Nemanja Trifunovic : Do you have a reference for that? I'm trying to find any docs on MSDN verifying your statement, without success.

Comment: @ildjarn: see here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.windows.wtl/16662

Comment: @Nemanja Trifunovic : Ah, I see; it seems some limited subset of ATL (sufficient to use WTL) comes with the WSDK, and full ATL comes with the DDK. Thanks again.

Comment: Is WTL worth learning (does it have a future) or is it best just to crank some code using examples available online and not bother with understanding entire library?

Comment: @kyrisu : I myself haven't used the majority of the library, but the basic fundamentals I do know have allowed me to write quite complex dialog applications. IMO, there are really only about 7 or 8 classes that need to be learned, then assuming one has an understanding of the WinAPI, everything just sort of falls into place.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend FLTK!! www.fltk.org

Answer (score 0):

Win32++ no mfc required neither ATL.

If you already know the winapi this is definitely for you. If not it helps a lot.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32-framework/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/framework.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want the smallest memory footprint and are using windows just directly call the [winforms](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/) routines provided by windows. This eliminates all the code in all these third party libraries. It's smaller and will be faster.